# Delete store view programmatically

Tags: magento-1.7, store-view, programmatically, delete

I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2

How can I delete store view by id programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/StoreController.php file there is the deleteStorePostAction(), the following code is used (just like every other Magento model can delete a record):

```
$model = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($itemId);
$model->delete();
```

Comment: Hi, After deleting the store view, I got this error message`Fatal error: Call to a member function getFrontNameByRoute() on a non-object in public_html/includes/src/__default.php on line 17507`

Comment: @gonzela2006 You should disable the compilation